# How to create a new account with same privileges

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I have a product whose main service is working with Administrator account named 'vertebrate'.Which way we can disable the ADMINISTRATOR account('vertebrate') and define a new administrator
account with the same privileges and GROUP participation as the default
ADMINISTATOR account without adversely affecting the product

Comment: If i disable vertebrate from Local Grops Users->Users side and create a new account there , and add that new account in Groups->Administrators side. Restart the service with filling This account...,Password....,ConfirmPassord...,is that the rite way

Comment: The real question here is ,will it affect our host file or service file.That mean if some entry is there in hostfile which is working administrator account,if i change or rename it will it makes any issues